# How to shorten DAG(Directed acyclic graph) generated by spark for a dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark sql. How can I shorten the DAG for a Spark Dataframe?

I tried using createnewDataFrame from the existing one but it takes alot of time for that.

sqlContext.createDataFrame(dataset.rdd, dataset.schema)

However, dataset.rdd takes a really long time and I see only 1 executor taking most of the time and causing the spill to disk.

Comment: Please, can you explain the question bit clear? If possible add more insights to your question.

Comment: you should search for `checkpoint`ing, this use used to break lineage

Comment: Checkpointing still will write to HDFS. I want to avoid writing to disk and break the lineage both at the same time since I have a huge intermediate dataframe.

Comment: If the problem is that the query plan is too complex and you want to break it, you can convert the DataFrame to RDD (by calling df.rdd) and then back to DataFrame. It will however convert the data from Tungsten format to JVM objects and back which is not for free.